# Python: Access to external process info

Tags: python, python-2.7, process, automation, ui-automation

I'm trying to figured out how to *manage* process with Python, although maybe C++ could be better for this. I'm using **Python 2.7** and **Ubuntu 14.04** is my OS.

Resume of what I'm trying to achieve:

- Send *actions* (not signals) to a running process *//* Interact with the UI of a process
- Read memory address value

My intention is to create a script to manage other softwares, something similar to what *Selenium* do with the browsers, but with any program. Maybe execute the process with Python using subprocess would give me the option to manage the process UI

---

**Send Actions/Interact with Running Process**

Right now I'm making this script in Linux using `psutil`. I know there are some Windows Libraries like `pywin` or `pywindll`.

I want to manage a process, for example any kind of software with UI(Skype, Gedit, Firefox..), I would like to know if it's possible to send an action to make a click in a button.

I don't want to manage the mouse in the computer, because let's say this *window* is "hidden" under other windows/stuff:

- Is possible once I have the process in my script to send a click to a button of the UI ? (or write into some textbox)

I'm using `psutil` to get the process, and I have a lot of options like:

- Get the memory mapping
- Get the threads of the process
- Kill the process
- CPU usage
- etc

But none of this actions seems to be what I'm looking for, that is to interact with the process UI...

- Is even possible what I'm trying to achieve ?
- Would be the simplest solution for this to send key strokes and mouse clicks ?

---

**Read Memory Address Value**

I've been using `scanmem` in Linux to find the memmory address of some variable, and once I've found the memory address I'm looking for, I want to use that address in Python to get the value stored in that address.

The closest thing I've found was using `ctypes`, something like:

```
from ctypes import string_at
from sys import getsizeof

mem_address = 0x7c3f 
value = string_at(id(mem_address), getsizeof(mem_address))
```

- Is this the simplest way to access a memory address in Python ?
- Is possible to modify/update this number in realtime ?
- How could I identify the memory address with IU ?

---

I was thinking that a program when is executed has to send the UI of the program to the OS, could be possible to *"capture"* the interface with python, and redirect to the OS ?

Something like executing the software *via* Python so may be possible to manage directly the UI

Comment: Search [python linux gui automation](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20linux%20gui%20automation&rct=j), also [this question may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619995/linux-gui-automation-api-in-python)

Comment: @AntonSavin thanks you very much for this link, it sounds very interesting!!

Comment: @AntonSavin Wow, from the top results of that google search, I was led to [autopy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopy/0.51) 0_o How did I miss this! +1

Comment: http://www.sikuli.org/

Comment: @Basilevs sikuli seems to be very similar to XPresser, it seems it's not finished, at least they didn't have too much information

Comment: Does the external program allow this kind of remote usage? You can use DBus which works quite well in ubuntu for this kind of interprocess communication (only if the external program allows controlling itself through DBus)

Comment: @hyades I'm asking the question in general, for any kind of software, I appreciate any kind of information about this and I'd like to read about what you're talking about, **DBus**, do you know any good book/web to read about it ? I'm going to google it

Comment: @Liarez
Don't think there are books around for this. Try out obvious wiki links and [this](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/). GDbus is what actually exists now. The command line version is [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/gdbus.html) with the bindings in [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/). Also you can see dbus messages pretty easily using d-feet

Comment: @AntonSavin I'm trying to use Xpresser but it seems to fail finding images on the screen, Did you try to use it ? Maybe you can give me some advice!

Comment: Did you find any good way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

I like the way you think :D UI automation is awesome

On the question itself, as far as I can tell, all the software that can interact with the GUI of processes is based on computer vision with OCR or reading the memory to get the object model of the UI. The latter is probably not universal, since different widget toolkits and approaches to building the UI will have different underlying models - it'll probably be more of a pain in the ass than CV+OCR.

If you want to see some stuff that has already been made for this purpose check out the [wikpedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools). You already know about Selenium but there's more - AutoIt and Sikuli where ones I checked for a similar project I want to make, in python. (AutoIt is BASIC-like -**YUCK**- and windows-only but Sikuli seems to be python related and is cross-platform - I checked them out ages ago so I don't remember details).

The really good news is that python has pretty good CV and OCR modules. My personal recommendation is [simplecv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleCV/1.3) which can wrap around opencv and other cv software and although I don't have a module of choice to recommend for OCR, I liked [python-tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/) the most when I was scouting for modules.

The approach is generally to take a snapshot of the GUI (graphicsmagick can do that plenty well and there's a python wrapper for it), make out where the elements are with CV, read the labels with OCR and that way you get a model for what is on the window. Then, you give your script instructions on what to do and when, based on where it is on the GUI. Since python can send mouse and keyboard events, you're golden. You can even use the `minidom` module to make an easier object model for your code.

*As an aside, the CV+OCR approach is also used by a Hearthstone-related app that takes snapshots of the game and reads the score, which it then tracks for the player so they can make up metrics. It's a more lightweight and easy approach than it seems - I checked out the code and it was quite easy to understand, despite the heavyweight technologies behind it.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the info! All the time I've been looking for info _OCR+CV_ was the most popular way to achieve this, the python-tesseract sounds like a very good library and I have to dig more about _simplecv_, anyway I appreciate very much the info!

Comment: @Liarez no problem! Is this a personal use project or are you going to release it? I'm very interested in this stuff at the moment, would love to see the work if you're going to do a public release.

Comment: Right now I'm just doing some kind of research and I'm planning to start a project, but small project I'll let you know if I achieve something interesting! Maybe we could share some ideas

Comment: @Liarez great ty! don't miss autopy, from that link in the OP, might save you work or have some interesting idea.

Comment: Ivy have you tried to send an "Enter" with Xpresser ? Something like write in the address bar of a browser and hit enter ? I've looking for documentation of Xpresser but didn't find too much

Comment: @Liarez Unfortunately, I haven't tried _any_ of these. All I know about this stuff is from research for a personal pet project, but I haven't had the time to even start working on it yet :(. Xpresser looks pretty cool though - I found [this link](http://chrismwayne.com/?tag=xpresser) on special keys. Indeed it seems quite undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for reading a variable from a program in a different process. Okay to simplify things a bit lets say for example you are trying to set up a communication between 2 different programs written in C++, lets say program A and program B. Relating to your query, we would have a case where program 'A' tries to access the value of a variable in program 'B'.

In this case I was thinking that you could use Boost Interprocess communication. So Boost Interprocess is a library in Boost that allows you to communicate between two processes using shared memory. You could use message queues from the library. For more information about that please check it out here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/interprocess.html

So going back to the example you need to write some code to support reading and writing variables between process. Lets say for now we can only read and write arrays and scalar values. So you need to maintain a data structure (preferably a map) that maps names of variables to a location in memory. Something like this:

```
#include <map>

//Somewhere in your program you have a variable
int my_var = 5;

//Declare a map of string mapping to 64 bit pointers
std::map<std::string, long long> var_map;

//At any point you decide to register the reference of this value
var_map["my_var"] = (long long) &my_var;

//Now that you have registered this value, 
//you can access it according to the name and 
//type cast it as well to a data structure that you like
int *ptr = (int *) var_map["my_var"];

//Now you can play around with this:
*ptr = 1024;
```

So I hope you see what I am trying to do here, so this type of code will exist in our case in Program B. The reason for this is so that Program A can send commands to Program B, saying I want to read a variable called "my_var".

So now comes the part of actual communication. In Boost Interprocess you can pack structs which could be read commands such as this:

```
typedef ReadCommand {
    char *var_name;
    int read_bytes;
}
```

Please read the documentation in Boost to know how to set up shared memory instances, because once you have set it up you can then send commands such as this:

```
     //Code in program A
     ReadCommand read_command;
     read_command.var_name = "my_var";
     read_command.bytes = 4;

     try {
        //Need to declare message_queue, please see doc in Boost
        message_queue_A->send(&read_command, sizeof(ReadCommand), 0);
     } catch (boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception &ex){
        //Handle exception
     }
```

Again going back to program B you can have code like this to receive the message:

```
    //Best to have struct definition in shared header file
    ReadCommand read_command_B;
    int some_priority;
    boost::interprocess::message_queue::size_type size_of_data_recvd;
    message_queue_B->receive(&read_command_B, sizeof(ReadCommand), size_of_data_recvd, some_priority);

    //use information in read_command_B 
    //to access var_map then use another 
    //message queue to send back data to 
    //Program A which will be expecting 
    //some information from program B.
```

Anyways once you have done that you can then integrate python with Boost python library. Hope this makes sense. Try it out and let me know if you have any trouble. This is not exact implementation but an idea that could provide the solution to your read value problem.

As for the sending actions problem, I am not really sure as to how to interact with UI in another process. Generally the vendor exposes API to the programmer which is used to interact with UI elements. What happens underneath is very difficult to understand and manipulate because in most cases they are closed source. If you have access to the source code in the API then that would be a different case. You could then use similar concepts as mentioned above to write to some location in another program which triggers events that occur in the UI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm trying to communicate with existing _external_ program, not with 2 different programs developed by me

Comment: ah okay, I thought when you said any program you meant any program written by you :).